# Good source of problems for Knapp's Elliptic Curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I'm studying elliptic curves (and eventually modular forms) out of Knapp's book because of the softer algebraic geometry prereqs. It's incredibly accessible but the problem is that I don't know I can apply any of it without a decent source of problems as a skill check. Without going to books like Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry or Silverstein's book, is there a decent resource of problems that are around the "level" of Knapp?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Shurman and Diamond's *A First Course in Modular Forms*. There is some material on elliptic curves in it, and many exercises at an undergraduate level.

Comment: (If you are affiliated with a university, you probably have access to Springer Online, in which case you can get the book in .pdf format legally and for free.)

Comment: I am guessing that by "Silverstein" you mean "Silverman"?  I think Silverman's book is the best source of problems in the area, although I agree that some of them require nontrivial algebraic geometry.  Nevertheless I might try working problems out of Silverman's book: you won't be able to solve all of those problems anyway (I have spent years doing research on elliptic curves and I can now solve most, but not all, of the problems in Silverman's book.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. And I did mean Silverman, thanks. I believe I've seen Shurman and Diamond's book while cruising through SpringerLink, but never checked it out. I'll check out Silverman's book from there, too.

Comment: Silverman and Tate's book Rational Points on Elliptic Curves (now second edition) has many excellent concrete problems in it, as do the earlier chapters of Husemoller's book Elliptic Curves. Since you want to avoid the heavy algebraic geometric approach, you probably want to work with particular examples of interesting elliptic curves in a more concrete fashion. The books referenced above promote this approach-as Knapp's book does.